# "Foldable" "Booklet" like Toodledo's one (pocketmod)

Tags: header-footer, columns, rotating

[image: Toodledo's foldable booklet]

How to achieve in pdfLaTeX foldable booklets similar to [those provided by Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/tools/booklet.php) ?

(to make question usable to others LuaTex, ConTeX and other systems answers are highly welcome)

Note: look, how many pages can fit on one paper sheet.

Comment: Please retag question appropriately

Comment: This is also called a 'pocketmod'

Comment: [`leaflet`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/leaflet) is not exactly what you want, is it?

Comment: BTW: [Search for “pocketmod” on www.ctan.org](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=pocketmod&search_type=description&search_type=filename&search_type=id).

Comment: pocketmod does not turn up any hits on that search. There is a pocketmod.sty that exists out there on the internet, but it is not existant on CTAN in 2019.

Comment: "pocketmod" booklets have the top of their mini pages at the outside of the letter/A4 sheet.  Similar yet different "origami" "minizine" booklets have the top of their mini pages at the center of the letter/A4 sheet.  The picture in the question suggests Toodledo provides a "origami" "minizine" booklet and *not* a "pocketmod" booklet.

Answer (score 14):

To make a booklet (8, 16, 32 pages), I use `pdfpages`. I use the following 3 steps:

1. I create an ordinary 8 pages PDF.
2. I use the following document as a first-pass (adapt for your type of composition):

   ```
   \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
   \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
   \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages=4]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=5]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=8]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=1]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=3, angle=180]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=6, angle=180]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=7, angle=180]{LivretHuit}
   \includepdf[pages=2, angle=180]{LivretHuit}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. I use the following (second) file for the second-pass.

   ```
   \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
   \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx,epsfig}
   \usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
   \begin{document}
   \includepdf[pages=-, nup=2x4, landscape, delta=0.75in 0, frame=false]{LivretHuitA}
   \end{document}
   ```

I have made version for 16 and 32 pages and for others compositions. I have made a little VBScript to automatise the operation.

My students like the little booklet quite a lot. Enjoy!

Answer (score 11):

this topic was addressed in a "glisterings" article in *tugboat* by peter wilson ([31:3, 2010, pp.177-183](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-3/tb99glister.pdf)).  the layout shown in the original posting appears as figure 5 in the "glisterings" article; there are many others as well.

Answer (score 9):

A while ago I created my pocketmod with `pgfpages` (see http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=909). This has the advantage to require only one LaTeX-run.

```
\documentclass[21pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[]{forloop}
\usepackage[]{blindtext}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[]{lmodern}
\newcounter{ct} 
\usepackage{pgfpages}

  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth} % landscaped by default
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
  \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}

  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=8,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
    current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
  }

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      rotation=180,%      
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.875\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{3}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      rotation=180,%      
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{4}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      rotation=180,%      
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{5}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      rotation=180,%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{6}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.125\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%

    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{7}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.375\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{8}
    {%
      border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
      resized width=.25\pgfphysicalwidth,%
      border code=\pgfusepath{stroke},%
      resized height=0.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
      center=\pgfpoint{.625\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%


\begin{document}

\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 9}{%
\blindtext
\clearpage

}
\end{document}
```

Be aware that the `pgfpages.sty`I had at that time was buggy.

```
% original code, not working
%\expandafter\ifx\csname pgfpages@p@\the\pgf@cpn @rotation\endcsname\relax%
 % \pgfscope%
%\else%
 % \pgflowlevel{\pgftransformrotate{\csname pgfpages@p@\the\pgf@cpn @rotation\endcsname}}%
%\fi%

\pgfscope% I used this change to make it work
            \expandafter\ifx\csname pgfpages@p@\the\pgf@cpn @rotation\endcsname\relax%
    \else%
  \pgflowlevel{\pgftransformrotate{\csname pgfpages@p@\the\pgf@cpn @rotation\endcsname}}%
\fi%
```

Answer (score 6):

I would like to present a ConTeXt solution. It makes use of the built-in
[Imposition](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition) capabilities.

To create a pocketmod layout you need to add the following two lines to your
setup area:

```
\setuppapersize [A7] [A4]
\setuparranging [1*8, rotated]
```

That's all. Here a complete example:

```
% these two lines do the whole magic
\setuppapersize [A7] [A4]
\setuparranging [1*8, rotated]

% the following lines are just added to create
% a more pleasant looking screen shot
\setuppagenumbering [location=]
\setupbackgrounds   [page] [background=color, backgroundcolor=gray]
\setupbodyfont      [sans, 58pt]
\setuplayout        [page]
\showframe

\starttext
% let's generate some pages
\dorecurse{8}
  {\null\vfill\centerline\recurselevel\vfill\null\page}
\stoptext
```

The result:

[image: result1]

[image: result2]

The `\setuppapersize` command instructs ConTeXt to print pages of the size
`A7` on an `A4` paper and `\setuparranging` sets up the desired imposition
scheme (how the individual pages are placed on the paper). More examples can
be found in the [chapter about page
design](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-pagedesign.pdf)
in the manual.

*Note:* I put the fold at the bottom of the page, not at the top, like shown in your illustration. If you really want the fold at the top, you need to create a custom imposition scheme, which is not hard:

```
\installpagearrangement pocketmod
  {\dosetuparrangement{4}{2}{8}{5}{3}
   \pusharrangedpagePOCKETMOD\poparrangedpagesTWO\relax}

\def\pusharrangedpagePOCKETMOD#1%
  {\advancearrangedpageN
   \reportarrangedpage\arrangedpageN
   \ifcase\arrangedpageN
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}100\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}001\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}011\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}021\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}031\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}130\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}120\arrangedpageA
   \or \handlearrangedpageXandY{#1}110\arrangedpageA
     \poparrangedpages
   \fi}
```

Replace `\setuparranging[1*8, rotated]` with `\setuparranging[pocketmod, rotated]` and the imposition is exactly as in the illustration with the fold at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Does the [`booklet`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booklet) package suit your needs?

Comment: "they can be printed as four pages per physical sheet of paper, two pages per side." does not sound like presented 8 pages per side.