# Half-A4 papersize - folded "the long way"

Tags: paper-size

I'm trying to create a booklet A4 which is folded "the long way", in other words such that the resulting page size is *not* an A5 page but rather two A6 "on top" of each other.

I changed the paper size successfully by loading the `article` class with the `a4paper` option and putting in my preamble

```
\setlength{\paperwidth}{.5\paperwidth}
```

However, this of course didn't change any of the lengths controlling text width, margins etc. So I assume there must be another, better way.

How?

Comment: Are you concerned about the folding as well? For example, are you trying to do something like this: PocketMod [#1](http://creativetechs.com/tipsblog/discover-pocketmod-the-low-tech-pda/), [#2](http://www.pocketmod.com/). In that sense, does the following help: [“Foldable” “Booklet” like Toodledo's one (pocketmod)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45607/5764)? Give some feedback.

Comment: @Werner: No, I'm not concerned with the folding - what I'm after is a pdf that works just like any other, with one page of the content on one page of the pdf, only with a different page size. I will then hand the pdf to a printing firm, that will print and fold everything for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` package, or the `memoir` document class for this. Here's an example with `geometry` (the kantian stuff is just to provide filler text):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=148mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\kant[1-8]
\end{document}
```

If that looks close to what you need, I suggest then reading the `geometry` or `memoir` documentation to make the other adjustments you need (such as tuning the margins).

Comment: Giving a `paperwidth` option to `geometry` did the trick! I loaded the `article` class with the `a4paper` option, so I could even set `paperwidth=.5\paperwidth` in the options to get it right =)

Comment: Even better! {Grrr -- I wasted, like, two minutes looking up the dimensions of A6 :)}