# Using the booklet package and the geometry package together

Tags: geometry, landscape, booklet

When I use the `booklet` package alone, it works just fine and produces the output I expect. However, when I combine it with the `geometry` package, it produces really bad output.

Here's my MWE. First, I comment out the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
%%\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[print]{booklet}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setpdftargetpages
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which gives me the following output. Notice the results are in portrait format - I want landscape:

[image: booklet w/o geometry package]

Here are results from the same file with the `geometry` line uncommented. The orientation is in landscape format, but the margins are all wrong. Notice how the text clips on the first page and overlaps on the second:

[image: booklet w/ geometry package]

How can I make the `geometry` package work with the `booklet` package? I am using TeXLive 2012, by the way.

p.s. My apologies for the unscaled images.

Comment: Please could you explain what do you want to do? Which document is `landscape`, the original or the booklet? If you read `booklet` manual (with command `texdoc booklet` or [here](http://texdoc.net/pkg/booklet)) you will find `landscape` option for landscape documents. Why do you need `geometry`?

Comment: I have a more complicated document with specific margins that I need `geometry` for.

Comment: @Ignasi In response to your first question - the original document is in portrait orientation. I would like to produce a document in landscape orientation, with two portrait pages per sheet.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem between `geometry` and `booklet`, but as an alternative solution you could forget `booklet` and use `geometry` to produce your main document and after that, use `pdfpages` to construct your booklet version. Look at: [booklet-with-a-specific-page-order-rule](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21839/booklet-with-a-specific-page-order-rule), [booklets-in-memoir-class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16967/booklets-in-memoir-class)

Comment: If you don't want to make two documents, you could also use `pgfpages` instead of `booklet`. Look at La Raison answer in [foldable-booklet-like-toodledos-one-pocketmod](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45607/foldable-booklet-like-toodledos-one-pocketmod)

Comment: That's almost what I want, but does it layout pages so they can be folded like a booklet?

Comment: Yes, `pdfpages` has an option `signature=...` where you say how many pages you want to fold. Please, look at the manual, everything is explained in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand you want to print a `booklet` version of your original document which consists in several specially dimensioned pages defined with `geometry` package help.

As an example, our original document looks like:

[image]

which was made with next code. Page dimensions are 10cm x 8cm.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[papersize={10cm,8cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[placement=center,angle=0,color=blue!95,scale=7]{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={-\thepage-}}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i in {1,...,24}
{
    \ \newpage
}

\end{document}
```

Now with [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkgs/pdfpages) help it's easy to produce a booklet version. If original document was `66267a.pdf`, next code will do it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-, nup=2x1, noautoscale, 
            frame, signature*=8, landscape, 
            angle=180, delta=0 1cm]{66267a}
\end{document}
```

`pdfpages` options means:

- `pages=-` include all original pages
- `nup=2x1` place two pages on a row
- `noautoscale` keep original page dimensions, otherwise they will scale to fit new page
- `frame` draw a frame around every original page
- `signature*=8` organize pages in 8 pages booklets
- `landscape` new page will be landscape
- `angle=180` not sure what it means, but works.
- `delta=0 1cm` introduces some separation between pages. If you don't need it, delete it.

As you can sse from next figure. It's supposed that you will use double side printing.

[image]